# Alias with two Fields using JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

i have a nasty SQl that i want transform in JOOQ

Here are the Query:

```sql
  SELECT 
    SUM(dpr.dpr_bruttopraemie_prt + dpr.dpr_sofortrabatt_prt) 
    , MAX(TO_NUMBER(DP1.dp_wert))  
      FROM deckungen deck, deckungspraemien dpr, 
        (SELECT dp.dp_id, dp.dp_wert 
              FROM  textbausteine txb, druckparameter dp 
              WHERE  dp.dp_txb_id = txb.txb_id 
              ) DP1 
      WHERE DP1.dp_id = :druckparameter_id;
```

As you can see, i need to make alias from a select with two Fields.

```sql
dp.dp_id, dp.dp_wert
```

that im going to used it on some other parts.

How i can i get it done?

i've seen

```java
.asField()
```

Funktion but it only make alias for one column.

PS: The actual Query are a lot more complicated. So i wrote a simpler one. 
With hoping that it's satisfied the SQL ORACLE Dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using the code generator, so you have generated objects available for your tables like `DECKUNGEN`. I'm also assuming you're using these static imports:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;                  // The jOOQ API
import static com.example.myapp.generated.Tables.*; // Your generated tables
```

You can then write:

```java
Deckungen deck = DECKUNGEN.as("deck");
Deckungspraemien dpr = DECKUNGSPRAEMIEN.as("dpr");
Textbausteine txb = TEXTBAUSTEINE.as("txb");
Druckparameter dp = DRUCKPARAMETER.as("dp");

Table<?> dp1 = table(
    select(dp.DP_ID, dp.DP_WERT)
   .from(txb, dp)
   .where(dp.DP_TXB_ID.eq(txb.TXB_ID))
).as("dp1");

Record2<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> result =
using(configuration)
  .select(
     sum(dpr.DPR_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_PRT.plus(dpr.DPR_SOFORTRABATT_PRT)),
     max(field("to_number({0})", BigDecimal.class, dp1.field(dp.DP_WERT))))
  .from(deck, dpr, dp1)
  .where(dp1.field(dp.DP_ID).eq(druckparameterId))
  .fetchOne();
```

#### Some explanations

- jOOQ currently doesn't have a built-in `TO_NUMBER()` function, but you can easily roll your own using [`DSL.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-) and similar overloads. For more detail, [refer to the manual's section about plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/)
- A derived table can be created most easily by using the [`DSL.table(Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-org.jooq.Select-) operator.
- Columns from a derived table can be dereferenced using `Table.field()` methods, in particular the [`Table.field(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#field-org.jooq.Field-), which tries to find a field by the same name as the argument field, retaining the argument field's type information.

#### Side-note

I don't think your query is correct as you're simply creating cartesian products between your tables `deck`, `dpr`, and `dp1`. Specifically, the `SUM()` is quite likely to be wrong, whereas `MAX()` is simply calculated inefficiently.